# How to tell if CoInitializeSecurity has already been called for a process?

Tags: com

Is there an easy way to tell if CoInitializeSecurity has already been called for a process?

I need to call CoInitializeEx and make use of a COM interface, but sometimes the calling code (which I have no control over) is calling me first, before it gets to CoInitializeSecurity, during its startup sequence, and then it falls over with E_RPC_TOO_LATE.

What I want to do is detect that CoInitializeSecurity has not been called yet, and delay for some small amount of time (on the order of ten seconds or so) until the caller has managed to make it to CoInitializeSecurity, before I continue on to CoInitializeEx.

Adding this delay solves the problem just fine, except, I don't like to have that delay on every single call -- just the very first one during startup. Hence, the desire to detect whether or not CoInitializeSecurity has been called yet.

Comment: Hmm, you detect that it is already called by getting E_RPC_TOO_LATE when you call it.  That can't be helpful.  Hard to see a cure if you just have no control over what other code does.  Talk to the owner of that code to work something out.

Comment: i see that nobody has answered your question; one which i need an answer to. i thought perhaps asking, *"How go get my current COM Threading Model?"* might do the trick (If we can *get* a threading model, then we know it's been initialized). But i cannot find an answer to that question either.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a work-around until I find something better:

Before calling CoInitializeEx, I call GetProcessTimes(GetCurrentProcess(), ...) so see how long it's been since the process has been created. If it has not been "long enough", I sleep for a bit. That gives my caller a fair chance to get to CoInitializeSecurity before I start hitting COM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about the context of the question. Can you clarify?

Based on your description, it sounds like your code runs in a DLL loaded by an EXE you don't quite control. An EXE would fully control its lifetime and would not be subject to these problems. Also, you seem to talk about CoInitialize and CoInitializeSecurity interchangeably. Do you really mean that you "need to call CoInitializeEx()", or "need to call CoInitializeSecurity()"?

Do you really need to set up the process-wide permissions? (that's not something a DLL should be doing; it should be done at the EXE level). Maybe something like CoSetProxyBlanket() is closer to what you need.

A bit more context might help clarify the problem.

(note: I'm without my trusty dead-tree reference materials for at least a week; I might not be able to help right away).

Comment: You are correct: my code is running in a DLL loaded by an EXE, and I don't control the EXE. I need to call CoInitializeEx, as I wrote, in order to create a COM interface and make some calls on it. I do not want to call CoInitializeSecurity, but COM is going to do this "for me" if nobody else has called it yet. I just need to let the app call if first, otherwise, the app itself fails on E_RPC_TOO_LATE, which I have no control over.

Comment: I do call CoSetProxyBlanket to set the security that I want on my interface -- that's not the problem. The problem is the order in which the EXE is initializing things, which I have to work around.